# How to hide list until search is done - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a list of places shown on a page. I also have a search form and button for that list. My issue is that the list is visible by default. I'd like the list -- filtered via search -- to be shown only once the search is conducted. While staying on the same page. I have the following code. The list is initially hidden well enough. But when I click on the search button, the list shows for 0.1 second and the disappears. I think I have something wrong here -- I'd really appreciate help.

JS

```
document.getElementById("place_list").style.display = "none";

function showPlace() {
  document.getElementById("place_list").style.display = "block";
}
```

Search button

```rb
<%= submit_tag("Search", name: nil, zip: nil, onclick:"showPlace()", class:'', style:'', id:"") %>
```

UPDATE: I used ChatGPT to find a preliminary solution, but it still has an issue: When move to a different page and then move back to this page with the list and the search, and move back via Link_to, the full list shows for some reason. I think JS is not loading. I searched and tried wrapping the JS code here in
`$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {}`. It's not working. Any clues would be much appreciated. I'm using Rails 7.